# Finding value of an atribute by giving its name

Tags: java, xml

```
<TestSuite name="FixTracerTests">

    <Test name="IM-Tracer" verbose="false">

        <Message action="send1" connection="IMTracerConnection">

            <Field name="MsgType" value="J" />

            <Field name="ABC" value="APPLE" /> <!-- Auto Generated.. -->

            <Field name="DEF" value="SAMSUNG" />

            <Field name="XYZ" value="HTC" />

            <Field name="GHI" value="SONY" />

        </Message>

    </Test>

</TestSuite>
```

I am trying to access the value of a particular attribute by using Java. For example if a user asks for a value for "name="ABC", then i should get "APPLE".  Can anybody help me in this ?

I have tried this thing :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File xmlfile = new File("file.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = db.parse(xmlfile);

    NodeList node = document.getElementsByTagName("Field");

    System.out.println("Enter name =");

    String name = userInputScanner.nextLine(); 

    NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();

    System.out.println(node.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue());

}
```

Comment: Could you include some code of what you have tried?

Comment: This is what i am trying

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/) can make it.
I didn't try it but there is my idea to integrate in the context :

```
SAXBuilder sxb = new SAXBuilder();
try {
  document = sxb.build(new File("Exercice2.xml"));
} catch(Exception e){}
root = document.getRootElement();
Iterator i = root.getChild("Test").getChild("Message").getChildren("Field").iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
{
  Element current = (Element)i.next();
  if(current.getAttributeValue("name") == nameDesired) {
  return current.getAttributeValue("value");
}
return null;
```

This is just an idea I've never used jdom but with what I've read it should be working with some adaptations to your own code.

Comment: As I said, I've just read the doc to answer your question. So the best should for you to read it maybe.

But I edited my answer to put what I think is good.

You may put a good file path.